# Not so public cloud pages in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

I am building a cloudpage but want to restrict it to be visible only within my company network.

I have a solution and it is working. I created a DE with the list of accepted IP ranges and used SSJS Platform.Request.ClientIP to compare the incoming browser page load source IP's with my accepted IP ranges.

However, I want to keep the acceptable list of IP ranges DE based on the Login IP allow list.

Is there a way to automate or query this Login IP Allow list. Greatly appreciate any comments. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It would be easier to make it as an authenticated page. IP can be spoofed very easily.

Comment: on the topic of authentication, you can build on a lot of great work for that: https://blog.email360.io/posts/cloudpage/create-authenticated-cloudpage.html

Comment: Thanks @JonasLamberty!! The blog is amazing....

Comment: here is another great resource to restrict access through the internal marketing cloud token. https://sf-marketing.com/marketing-cloud-user-validation-on-cloudpages/